# Getting one extra contact even after specifying filter condition for "LastModifiedTime"

Tags: php, office365

Suppose there are 40 modified or newly added contacts in Office365, when my application tries to sync using REST APIs it is fetching 40 contacts. If I again re-sync by specifying below filters

> ```
> Array (
> [$top] => 7
> [$orderby] => DateTimeLastModified
> [$filter] => DateTimeLastModified gt 2015-01-06T07:23:59Z )
> ```

I am getting last record that was sent in the previous request which should have not come in this request.

Please advise if there is any mistake in the filters that I have specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the value you're passing in your filter is the actual value of DateTimeLastModified on the contact that gets returned. This is likely due to how Exchange stores date/times. Times are stored with milliseconds, but as you can see from the way the REST API exposes it, the value only has seconds.

So while the REST API says the DateTimeLastModified value is 2015-01-06T07:23:59Z, there are some unexposed milliseconds in the value in the Exchange database. Let's say for example the real value is 2015-01-06T07:23:59.050Z. When this value is compared with 2015-01-06T07:23:59Z, it is greater, so it gets returned. To work around this, you could add a second to the time in the filter, which should cause that contact not to return.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. If I add a second to the last modified time and set it as filter then for some cases I may lose few contacts that were created in the gap of 1 second ? Is there any workaround to avoid this?

Comment: No, not that I can think of. You might be best off to deal with the repeated result instead.

Comment: Thank you. It can be an exceptional case where in I might miss one or two records.